# How many possible ways to reduce time complexity by replacing Arrays stream

Tags: java, arrays

For practice purpose,
I've created a small program to arrange two arrays of people accordingly their height.

**Example:**

```
There are two groups of 3 people
Position: 0 1 2
Group 1   2 3 5
Group 2   6 4 2

With the above order, only position 02 is correct.
Constrain always group 2 people should have less height than group 1

Now, Let's re-arrange them. 
Please see beneath,
position: 0 1 2
Group 1   2 5 3
Group 2   6 4 2
Here, Possible Arrangement is 2 with position 1, and 2 is correct.
```

To arrange them I've build one java program.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Arrangement {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            Integer noOfArrangement, currentArrangement, noOfPeople, totalArranged;
            ArrayList<Long> group1, group2;

            {
                noOfArrangement = currentArrangement = noOfPeople = totalArranged = 0;
                group1 = new ArrayList<Long>();
                group2 = new ArrayList<Long>();
            }

            noOfArrangement = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            while (currentArrangement < noOfArrangement) {
                totalArranged = 0;

                noOfPeople = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                group1 = (ArrayList<Long>) Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" ")).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
                group2 = (ArrayList<Long>) Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" ")).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());

                if (group1.size() != noOfPeople || group2.size() != noOfPeople) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                Collections.sort(group1);
                Collections.sort(group2);

                for (int l = 0; l < group2.size(); l++) {
                    for (int w = 0; w < group1.size(); w++) {
                        if (group2.get(l) < group1.get(w)) {
                            totalArranged++;
                            group1.remove(w);
                            group2.remove(l);
                            l = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(totalArranged);
                currentArrangement++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Input:
1
10
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
output:
7
```

> Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split("
>   ")).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList())

**The question is:** This aloft line is taking too much of time is there any other possible ways to reduce time complexity by replacing Arrays stream?

Comment: time complexity is O(n) and I don't see how you can reduce that. But getting rid of all the boxing/unboxing operations will improve performance. So you could use arrays of `int` instead of lists of `Integer`. Also not sure why you are using longs when ints would do.

Comment: Yes, That can be improved. Thank you @assylias.
But still, Need a solution to reduce the time complexity.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya I don't understand the question but from what I understand I can tell you: If you have to check every element, then the complexity is *O(n)*. The complexity is not about some programming hacks to improve performance. It's inherently an attribut of a problem or algorithm.

Comment: Yes, Definitely agreed with your ( @akuzminykh ) last statement _"It's inherently an attribute of a problem or algorithm"_ That's why I've tried multiple approaches/algorithms and come up with the least but not the last solution.
Here, If you have any queries on understanding the question and you can suggest a better algorithm to resolve problem statement. let me know.